# How do I surpress a jsHint message saying app is never used in my AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code looks like this:

/*global angular, _ */

```
var app = angular
    .module('app',
    ['appServicesModule', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'admin', 'common', 'home',
        'java', 'ngAnimate', 'test', 'ngResource', 'jmdobry.angular-cache'
    ])
    .config([
        '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$sceProvider', '$stateProvider',
        function (
    ...
    ...
```

The application works fine but I get a jsHint error saying "app variable is never used". Am I doing something wrong and is there a way to surpress this in the jsHint comment at the top of the file?

Comment: If you are not doing anything with `app` variable, you can just remove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 angular
    .module('app',
    ['appServicesModule', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'admin', 'common', 'home',
        'java', 'ngAnimate', 'test', 'ngResource', 'jmdobry.angular-cache'
    ])
    .config([
        '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$sceProvider', '$stateProvider',
        function (
```

This should work, you don't need to get it to a variable. And if you need to get it back in somewhere else you can get it like this,

```
var app=angular.module('app');
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding the `"unused": false,` flag in your `.jshintrc` file

See possible [jshintrc options](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/) & their explanations

Note: this is a global setting and will disable warning for all unused variables.